# How to print the value of pointers that's point to type of class c++

Tags: c++

How to print the value of pointers that's point to type of class in function print as globe i trying but idk how to print the value of x and y that's pointer point to. 
this code:

```
int main(){

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
    class POINT { 
        public:
            POINT (){ } 
            POINT (int x, int y){ x_=x; y_=y;}
            int getX (){ return x_; } 
            int getY (){ return y_; }
            void setX (int x) { x_ = x; }
            void setY (int y) { y_ = y; }
        void print( ) { cout << "(" << x_ << ","<< y_ << ")";}
        void read( ) {cin>> x_; cin>>y_;}
        private:        
            int x_;
         int y_;
};  
 void print (   POINT * p1Ptr , POINT * p2ptr){
    POINT* x= p1Ptr; POINT*y=p2ptr;
    cout<<x<<y;
} 
int main(){

 POINT p1(3,2);
 POINT p2(6,6);
  POINT *p1Ptr=&p1;
    POINT *p2Ptr=&p2;
    double d=0.0;
     double *dPtr=&d;
     p1Ptr->getX();
     p2Ptr->getX();
     p1Ptr->getY();
     p2Ptr->getY();
     print ( &p1, &p2); 
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is that `print` function *supposed* to be doing *besides* needlessly making copies of its parameters, then sending them (rather than the parameters) to an output stream?

Comment: Implement a global function PrintXY that receives pointer to object of type POINT and prints its data member ( x and y )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure this is what you mean, but how about:

```
class POINT { 
public:
    // skipped some of your code...

    void print(std::ostream& os) const
                         // note ^^^^^ this is important
    {
        // and now you can print to any output stream, not just cout
        os << "(" << x_ << ","<< y_ << ")";
    }

    // skipped some of your code...
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const POINT& pt)
{
    pt.print(os);
    return os;
}

void print (POINT * p1Ptr , POINT * p2ptr){
    cout << *p1Ptr << *p2ptr;
}
```

Comment: +1 This is a *very* common approach (I use it all the time, in fact). The title of the question would probably have done better as "How do i override the stream insertion operator for my custom types?"

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You want `cout << *x << *y;` (or `cout << *p1Ptr << *p2ptr;` as there is really no point (pun intended!) in copying the pointer to `POINT` inside the function).</strike>

Sorry about that, I thought there was an `operator<<` for `POINT`.

You need to use `p1ptr->print(); p2ptr->print();` to use the functions you already have.

Comment: i am sorry it's    : cout << *p1Ptr << *p2ptr;

Comment: +1 for showing the immediate and simple fix, although I think it would help the OP to consider the much more flexible and scalable solution of my answer to benefit in the future when the code grows.

Comment: @DanielFrey: Yes, that is indeed a "neater" fix - but more complex and probably not what was originally intended, given the existence of the `print` function.

Comment: You can always add a default: `void print(std::ostream& os=std::cout) const { ... }`.